# Where is normal memory mappings?

Tags: synchronization, posix, mutex, shared-memory, qnx

In the description of QNX Neutrino RTOS and also Blackberry10 OS ([here](http://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/native/reference/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/p/pthread_mutex_init.html)) for `pthread_mutex_init()`, it is said the following:

> You should allocate synchronization objects only in normal memory
>   mappings. On certain processors (e.g. some PPC ones), atomic
>   operations such as calls to pthread_mutex_lock() will cause a fault if
>   the control structure is allocated in uncached memory.

I have defined my `Mutex` out of any function and I'm getting 'memory fault' error while trying to do `pthread_mutex_init()`. So, I'm wondering what do "normal memory mappings" and "uncached memory" terms mean? Where should I define my `Mutex` lock?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using ARM architecture.

ARM architecture supports three types of memory-

1 - Strongly Ordered - Non-cacheable

2 - Device - Non-cacheable ( For memory mapped peripheral)

3 - Normal - cacheable

As per your description, you are supposed to allocate the muxtex structure from Normal memory. For normal program execution Normal memory is used. You problem looks unrelated to this. Please check the memory allocation function return value.

For detailed description about ARM memory types, go to the ARM website.